# How to load Omniglot on Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, pytorch

I'm trying to do some experiments on the Omniglot dataset, and I saw that Pytorch implemented it. I've run the command

```
from torchvision.datasets import Omniglot
```

but I have no idea on how to actually load the dataset. Is there a way to open it equivalent to how we open MNIST? Something like the following:

```
train_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root='./data', 
                            train=True, 
                            transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                            download=True)
```

The final goal is to be able to open training and test set separately and run experiments on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do exact same transformations as `Omniglot` contains `images` and `labels` just like `MNIST`, for example:

```
import torchvision

dataset = torchvision.datasets.Omniglot(
    root="./data", download=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
)

image, label = dataset[0]
print(type(image))  # torch.Tensor
print(type(label))  # int
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of train and test , Omniglot dataset uses background and evaluation terminology instead.

```
background_set = datasets.Omniglot(root='./data', background=True, download=True, 
transform=transforms.ToTensor())
```